# Calculating percentage of each sector in Adobe Flex Pie Chart

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, pie-chart, mxml

I have made a donut pie chart in adobe flash builder 4.5 which shows tool tip for each sector during mouse hover. I wanted to know how the application is calculating and displaying the percentage of each sector even though i am just providing values in array collection with no formulas being used in the code given below..

Please Help

My complete code..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/13/creating-donut-shaped-pie-charts-using-the-innerradius-style/ -->
 <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
            layout="vertical"
            verticalAlign="middle"
            backgroundColor="white">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function labelFunc(item:Object, field:String, index:Number, percentValue:Number):String {
            return item.name + ": " + '\n' + "AVG: " + item.avg;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl">
    <mx:source>
        <mx:Array>
            <mx:Object name="R Winn" obp=".353" slg=".445" avg=".300" />
            <mx:Object name="P Feliz" obp=".290" slg=".418" avg=".253" />
            <mx:Object name="O Vizquel" obp=".305" slg=".316" avg=".246" />
            <mx:Object name="B Molina" obp=".298" slg=".433" avg=".276" />
            <mx:Object name="R Durham" obp=".295" slg=".343" avg=".218" />
        </mx:Array>
    </mx:source>
</mx:ArrayCollection>



<mx:PieChart id="chart"
             height="100%"
             width="100%"
             innerRadius="0.5"
             showDataTips="true"
             dataProvider="{arrColl}" >
    <mx:series>
        <mx:PieSeries labelPosition="callout"
                      field="avg"
                      labelFunction="labelFunc">
            <mx:calloutStroke>
                <mx:Stroke weight="0"
                           color="0x888888"
                           alpha="100"/>
            </mx:calloutStroke>
            <mx:radialStroke>
                <mx:Stroke weight="0"
                           color="#FFFFFF"
                           alpha="20"/>
            </mx:radialStroke>
            <mx:stroke>
                <mx:Stroke color="0"
                           alpha="20"
                           weight="2"/>
            </mx:stroke>
        </mx:PieSeries>
    </mx:series>
</mx:PieChart>

    </mx:Application>
```

Here is the screen-shot of the output i.e pie chart

[image: Donut-piechart]

I want to know how the value 23.2% is being displayed as tool tip for the orange sector even though I'm not writing it anywhere in my code..if any function of the sdk is being called to calculate the percentage then where is it??

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right - Flex does this for you already.
I'm doing something similar myself so sorry for the necropost. This requires some quick diving into the SDK, specifically to PieSeries.as, line 1772 in the `updateMapping` function where the `percentValue` property is set.

```
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
     _renderData.cache[i].percentValue = _renderData.cache[i].number/total;
 }
```

`_renderData` can be accessed by calling the `items` property of the series, found on line 468.

```
override public function get items():Array /* of PieSeriesItem */
{
    return _renderData ? _renderData.filteredCache : null;
}
```

So if you wanted to know the percent of the item at index 3 in your PieSeries, you'd do the following:

```
var item3Percent:Number = chart.series[0].items[3].percentValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a custom formula to calculate this percentage, it's a standard calculation and one that the pie chart has to preform in order to work what size of the pie to give to each value.

All the information it needs to do this is provided when you set `field` and `dataProvider` on the `chart` object. While I can't provide you with the exact code that is run here is a simple approximation:

```
function getRowPercentValue(row:Object):Number
{
    return (row[field] / getTotalFieldValue()) * 100
}
function getTotalFieldValue():Number
{
    var returnVal:Number = 0;
    for each(var row:Object in dataProvider)
    {
        returnVal += row[field];
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

note this is a bit of pseudo-code, the pie chart will be more optimised than this and will do clever things (like use `row.valueOf()` if `field == undefined` etc, etc.)

As to why it's displayed there, that will be part of the tooltip renderer, you can see your custom `labelFunc` working with the lines coming off the chart

Comment: In the above example the percentage is being calculated without using any user defined function..I just wanted to know how??

Comment: Apparently the code is already built in..I'm just having trouble locating it in the mxml code..

Comment: i didn't mean the whole sdk code..I meant the code given above by me..around 60 lines of code..

Comment: @OlinKirkland It appears that the comment you are referring too has been removed (not by me). Above I have offered a method to calculate such details without needing to ascertain how Flex does it, the comment about "500mb of source" was probably a hyperbolic assessment of the unnecessary effort required to identify where and how Flex does it.

I am not / was not trying to sound harsh, but I will admit to being quite short. Though I'd ask for you to avoid name calling, its entirely unnecessary. If there's something I've missed please feel free to comment or add your own answer.